# Cannot subscript a value of type '[OnboardingViewController]'

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

I'm creating an array of ViewControllers and XCode is giving me lip about trying to access them via bracket notation. The following code instantiates two OnboardingViewControllers (subclasses of UIViewController).

```
var controllers = [OnboardingViewController]()
var controller = OnboardingViewController()
let totalOnboardingPages = 2

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    populateControllersArray()
    createPageViewController()
}

func populateControllersArray(){
    for i in 0...totalOnboardingPages-1 {
        controllers.append(getPageController(i))
    }
}

func getPageController(itemIndex: Int) -> OnboardingViewController {
    var controller = OnboardingViewController()

    switch itemIndex {
    case 0:
            // Welcome
            controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnboardingWelcomeViewController") as! OnboardingViewController
    case 1:
        // Find Facebook Friends
        controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnboardingFacebookViewController") as! OnboardingViewController

    default: ()
    }

    controller.itemIndex = itemIndex
    return controller
}

func createPageViewController() {
    let pageController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnboardingPageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
    pageController.dataSource = self

    // BREAKS ON THIS LINE
    pageController.setViewControllers(controllers[0], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

    pageViewController = pageController
    addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
    view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
    pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}
```

The error occurs in `createPageViewController()`:

```
pageController.setViewControllers(controllers[0], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[OnboardingViewController]'

OK, but when I set a breakpoint at that line I can `po controllers[0]` and get my controller:

```
<MyApp.OnboardingWelcomeViewController: 0x618000086080>
```

In fact, the very next function I have this which XCode doesn't complain about.

```
return controllers[controller.itemIndex - 1]
```

`controllers` is not optional and I have no idea what's going on here. I've cleaned, deleted the DerivedData directory and restarted XCode. Help!

Comment: The first argument to `setViewControllers` is an array of view controllers, not, a view controller - note the 's' at the end. I agree the error message is completely misleading but you seem to get that a lot with Swift.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to pass an array of ViewControllers into `setViewControllers()`. My corrected code is:

```
pageController.setViewControllers([controllers[0]], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Thanks to Paulw11 for the helpful comment.